# Log4j2 logs to file and in IDE but not when run from CLI

Tags: java, testing, maven-3, log4j2

I usually try to figure out things on my own and it works most of the time, but I am stuck with this one so please help. Which seemed like an easy thing ended up being a huge headache. 
So the problem is that there no line of log being outputted to Console when running mvn test from the CLI. Things work fine when I run my tests from IDE and also writing logs to file works in both scenarios. Tried different things, but always with the same result
Below is my log4j config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" name="MainConfiguration">
<Properties>
    <Property name="logFileDirectory">target/logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t - %tid] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${logFileDirectory}/test.log"
                 filePattern="${logFileDirectory}/archive/logs/test_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t - %tid] [%c{1}] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Update: The lo4j2.xml is located in src/main/resources. Tried to add a log4j2-test.xml in src/test/resources, but the result did not change. Also, all of my code is test related so it's in src/test/java. Just in case, here are the two dependencies in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your project layout. Where is your xml located in the project?

Comment: @meskobalazs The lo4j2.xml is located in src/main/resources. Tried to add a log4j2-test.xml with the same contents, in src/test/resources, but the result did not change. Also, all of my code is test related so it's in src/test/java.

Comment: It's likely not your logging config that's the problem, but Maven. I haven't had much experience with Maven itself, but often build tools capture the console output of tests and collate them into JUnit "results" XML or HTML files.

You can easily test whether or not Maven is the problem by writing a test that includes a `System.out.println("Hi");` somewhere, and see if that comes out when run through Maven.

Comment: @user31601 You're right, no system output as well when running maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel dumb, but anyways... After going over and over the pom and config files, realized that the maven surefire plugin was configured to redirect test output to file. My only consolation for missing such an obvious thing is that I did not write this myself. But still, so much wasted time... Here's what was wrong:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```